# Firefox browser randomly clicks on links when moving mouse over them

Tags: firefox

Firefox version 39.0.3 with Adblock Plus and NoScript enabled at all times.

This happens on some sites more than others, most prominently Bloomberg News (https://www.bloomberg.com). Also happened on the Daily Beast (http://www.thedailybeast.com).

The browser unpredictably behaves as if it clicked on random links on the pages when mousing over areas or scrolling (no clicks on any device button). This happens even with Adblock Plus and NoScript blocking everything (so there can't be a malicious JavaScript generating clicks).

This behavior is dangerous. The browser shouldn't be allowed to register nonexistent clicks. Any idea why it's happening and how to prevent it?

Other obvious causes already ruled out:

- Problems with the mouse/configuration/drivers. This only happens on specific and somewhat rare web sites. I haven't observed these "ghost-clicks" in any other program either.
- Malware/adware/crapware. Already scanned for that and found nothing.
- Whitelisted JavaScripts. I block all scripts by default and only allow select scripts on trusted sites. News sites never receive JavaScript authorization.
- Other scripting and programming languages. In case you haven't figured out that I'm digitally paranoid, I permanently disabled Flash, Java, and other plugins.

Comment: I'd first say update your Firefox. You're running a version for 2015. The current stable release is 50.0.3.

Comment: I updated Firefox early this year to receive patches for Spectre/Meltdown exploits. I'm still getting these shadow clicks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 39 is **over two years old now**. I would suggest that you update it first!

Next up, try going to `about:profiles` and restarting Firefox with addons disabled (it'll disable all of them). If that still doesn't work, try creating a new profile from there, or exiting Firefox and going to Start > Run and entering `firefox -profilemanager`. This should rule out a number of potential issues, or help you identify the culprit.